# How to remove elements with same parameter in a dart class list?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is the dart class:

```
class CategoriesContent {
  final String category;
  final String image;
  final int categoryNumber;

  CategoriesContent({this.category, this.image, this.categoryNumber});
}
```

How to remove elements in

```
List<CategoriesContent> categoryList;
```

Such that no elements with same category number remain.

`.toSet().toList()` doesn't work.

Example addition

```
categoryList.add(CategoriesContent(
    image: x["img"][0],
    category: x["category"],
    categoryNumber: ii));
}
```

Comment: You need to show more of the code you have tried and examples of your data.

Comment: Agreed, please illustrate the ProductList model.

Comment: Added example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you save the ids separately and call toSet() to make unique then you loop through your list and keep only those

```
final categoryNumbers = categoryList.map((e) => e.categoryNumber).toSet();
categoryList.retainWhere((x) => categoryNumbers.remove(x.categoryNumber));
```

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove an element in a list you can use `removeWhere` function
i putted `List<CategoriesContent> categoryList;` in a Hypothetical class ,but you should find its class and instantiate that class
this is the class that contains the `categoryList`

```
class Name {
  List<CategoriesContent> categoryList; 
}
```

you should instantiate the class in where you want to use it

```
var name = Name();
```

then where ever you want to remove that element you can use `removewhere` function i putted it in a onPressed function so whenever user clicks on the button that element would be removed , you can use it in initstate or wherever you suppose

```
 onPressed: (){
        name.categoryList.removeWhere((element) => element.category == '1');
        },
```

i putted `string 1` by default but you should put what you want to remove for example if you want to remove mobile category you should say

```
element.category == 'mobile'
```

and if you want to remove where elements are wuth same parameter you should say

```
for (var item in name.categoryList) {
          name.categoryList.removeWhere((element) => element == item);
        }
```

or

```
name.categoryList.removeWhere((element) => element.category == element.category);
```

i'm not sure about the second one

tell me the result